# Makefile: CreateProcess(...) failed. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: makefile, mingw-w64

I'm trying to deal with Makefiles and wrote a simple "program":

```
DELETE_COMMAND := del
COMPILER := gcc
SOME_TEXT := lalalalalalalalalalalal!!!

all: sum.o even.o main.o pi.o
    @$(COMPILER) -o output.exe sum.o even.o main.o pi.o
    SOME_TEXT_2 := $(subst la,La,$(SOME_TEXT))
    @echo $(SOME_TEXT_2)

clean:
    @$(DELETE_COMMAND) *.o
    @$(DELETE_COMMAND) output.exe

sum.o: sum.c sum.h
    @$(COMPILER) -c sum.c

main.o: main.c sum.h pi.h
    @$(COMPILER) -c main.c

pi.o: pi.c pi.h even.h
    @$(COMPILER) -c pi.c

even.o: even.c even.h
    @$(COMPILER) -c even.c
```

But I get the following error:

> SOME_TEXT_2 := LaLaLaLaLaLaLaLaLaLaLal!!!
>   process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, SOME_TEXT_2 := LaLaLaLaLaLaLaLaLaLaLal!!!, ...) failed.
>   make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
>   make: *** [Makefile:7: all] Error 2

The problem is caused by this line:

```
    SOME_TEXT_2 := $(subst la,La,$(SOME_TEXT))
```

but I have no idea what the problem is.
I'm using make from mingw-w64 on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the rule...

```
all: sum.o even.o main.o pi.o
        @$(COMPILER) -o output.exe sum.o even.o main.o pi.o
        SOME_TEXT_2 := $(subst la,La,$(SOME_TEXT))
        @echo $(SOME_TEXT_2)
```

Assuming all lines except the first begin with a tab character then each command will be run in a separate shell.  But...

```
SOME_TEXT_2 := $(subst la,La,$(SOME_TEXT))
```

is not valid shell syntax -- it looks like it's supposed to be interpreted by `make`.

If the intent is simply to modify the variable `SOME_TEXT` and print the result then you can have either...

```
all: sum.o even.o main.o pi.o
        @$(COMPILER) -o output.exe sum.o even.o main.o pi.o
        @echo $(subst la,La,$(SOME_TEXT))
```

or, let `make` assign to `SOME_TEXT_2`...

```
SOME_TEXT_2 := $(subst la,La,$(SOME_TEXT))

all: sum.o even.o main.o pi.o
        @$(COMPILER) -o output.exe sum.o even.o main.o pi.o
        @echo $(SOME_TEXT_2)
```